# Перестали работать апплеты в Internet Explorer 11

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet

В общем дела обстоят так:

Я участвую в разработке сайта с использованием апплетов.

Окружение:

- Internet Explorer 11 (контора настаивает)
- Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise x64
- jdk 8.65
- доменная система с широким спектром всевозможных политик безопасности

С самим апплетом работаю не так чтобы часто, но раз-два в неделю приходится (как карта ляжет).Так вот, в течении последней неделю у меня перестали загружаться апплеты.

Хочу сразу обратить внимание на тот факт, что я **НЕ ЗНАЮ КОГДА ИЛИ ПОСЛЕ ЧЕГО** они перестали загружаться, так как говорил что работаю с ними не часто.
Для того чтобы немножко прояснить ситуацию поясню что значит фраза **не загружаются**.

У меня не поднимается процесс виртуальной машины, не появляется окно консоли (галочка постоянного отображения проставлена), не выскакивает окно подтверждения запуска апплета и т.д. Проблема выглядит ровно так как она звучит. Апплеты просто не грузятся не на одном сайте (даже java.com).

Сейчас таких два компа. Между собой не связаны. Гуглю уже второй день, но ничего не помогает. Я в этой конторе рядовой программист, и никаких доступов к АД, ГП и прочим экзотическим животным у меня нет.

Из проверенного и проделанного:

- В IE поддержка java script включена
- В Java Configuration кеша чистил (да и вообще выключил)
- В Java Configuration настройки сбрасывал
- В Java Configuration в список довереных сайт и файлы добавлял
- В Java Configuration галочкка Enable Java content in browser проставлена
- В IE кеша чистил, настройки сбрасывал, настройки для зон тоже сбрасывал.
- jdk переустанавливал (4 раза: 8.65, 7.79, 8.60, 8.65)
- Комп перезагружал много раз
- Другой пользователь с равными и разными правами (доменная система) на моем компе - не работает
- Мой пользователь на другом компе - все работает

Все проверялось на одной и той же ревизии одного и того же проекта.

Ребят помогите пожалуйсте. Очень не хочется прибегать к переустановке системы.

Comment: У нас в конторе такая же ерунда творится. И дело именно в обновлениях KB...
Версия IE везде одна и та же, а версии его обновлений - разные. На каких то работают на каких то нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй раз возникла похожая проблемма.

На этот раз причина нашлась быстрее.

Работать перестало после переустановки джавы (нужно было удалить и проверить работу сайта без джавы). Когда поставил обратно - апплеты не работают

3 дня ковырялся, пока не заметил что разрядность установленного в ИЕ плагина для джавы - **х64**, а у браузера **х32** (*почему-то на компе не оказалось х64 ИЕ о_О*)

Заменил ***JRE х64*** на ***JRE х32*** - Заработало

Так как у нас проходит централизованное обновление ПО, вполне возможно что прошлый раз все исправило именно оно (*централизованное обновление Java послтавило **JRE x32***), а обновления никакого отношения к делу не имели

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась также не ожиданно как и возникла.

Сегодня утром, установились обновления для Windows 7. 
Точно не уверен, но похоже что помогли имеено они.

- Internet Explorer 11 - KB3100773
- .NET Framework 3.5.1 - KB3097989
- Windows 7 x64 - KB3081320
- Windows 7 x64 - KB3092601
- Windows 7 x64 - KB3097877
- Windows 7 x64 - KB3101246
- Windows 7 x64 - KB3101722
- Windows 7 x64 - KB3101746